# How to make wavy header or hero image with CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

First i will say thank you for your help on this...i am not web designer, and i have question about the layout that i need to make...there's any solution how to make masking wavy on bottom of hero image? if can give the example that would be very help! thank you so much before..here i am attached what layout that i need to make..thank you so much before